# Site promotion ideas?

Tags: discussion, moderators, site-promotion

Moderators, serious Stackers and casual users,

Within the coming weeks, we here at Stack Central will be putting a little bit of effort into promoting the Android site. We're hoping to get you involved.

Please chime in with any ideas -- from traditional (banner ads, giveaways, forum outreach, etc.) to off-the-wall (Can we get an ape to take a self-portrait with the new HTC?).

What do you think will help grow Android.SE into a bigger and better site?

All input is welcome.

We look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: The biggest way of attracting users I can think of is by small kind of contests and forums.

Answer (score 6):

Gaming has gotten great traffic via asking users who get a new game to post as many questions as they can.  This provides the benefits of seeding (more questions) without the drawbacks (crappy, contrived questions) since the questions are intended to be about actual problems the gamers encounter.  It's simply prompting them to ask the question on Gaming rather than trying to solve the problem on their own.  Having so many questions about the game on the day of release and thereafter means that Gaming gets a huge chunk of the search traffic for the game.

We could try a similar thing when Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) is released.  Everyone with a flagship device could upgrade immediately and start asking questions, as could anyone who gets a new device with the OS.  Probably it won't work as well as on Gaming, but it's sure to be better than nothing.

Comment: I sort of did this on the first day the Amazon Appstore was open.  [This question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7254/how-can-i-get-apps-from-the-amazon-app-store-from-an-unsupported-region) quickly became my most viewed.

Comment: we can also get new devices like tablets in the hands of high rep users here.

Comment: Crashing the boards with questions in anticipation of a major release is certainly something we are going to try to do in the near future. And as @Jeff Atwood mentioned, we are going to put some resources into getting new devices and apps to high rep users like yourself. I'm now compiling a release calendar of devices and apps coming out soon. Does something like this exist on the site already? Perhaps in Wiki form? Does something like this exist somewhere else?

Comment: That is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

My best guess would be banner ads on other common Android support sites; AndroidForums, XDA, Android Central, stuff like that. As far as users already on the site, you could to exclusive badges or special reputation-rewards for creative things.

Answer (score 4):

Contests/giveaways are typically what other Android blogs/sites/forums do to try and get more users.  Might be worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah, something like "random devices to new users who gain X rep" (to attract people) plus "random devices to high-rep users" (to keep people grinding XP) could work quite well.  Though I am obviously biased in wanting the second part :P