# Is this site active? (sorry for asking)

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering how much this site is really active.

Of 5 questions I asked, 3 received no answer at all. That's a pretty high number, I've never encountered anything like that on any SE site so far.

Sure, it might be just chance, but still I think it was worth to ask here.

(looking at the main page, there's a whole lot of unanswered posts too, so I guess it's not only me)

Comment: Don't mean any offence by this, but you've asked 5 questions and not answered anyone else's questions at all. To get answers to questions we need people to answer questions.

Comment: @GAThrawn: while this is technically true, you have to know the answers to give them. I help where I can, I search for help where I need. Looks like this SE only intersects the latter.

Comment: Additionally according to the [site directory](http://stackexchange.com/sites), we currently have 85% questions answered, while Stack Overflow has 81% of questions answered. We're in roughly the bottom quarter of SE sites for answered questions, but we're not at the bottom and the "original trilogy" are all below us (notably Apple which has the most similar remit to us is right beside us in the listings).

Comment: @GAThrawn: this covers the whole site history, which is irrelevant since I'm talking about *now*. Currently in front page 12/48 questions are unanswered (25%), and when I asked this question IIRC they were even more.

Comment: The front page isn't a good metric for any site, you need to give people time to answer.  It fluctuates constantly and is heavily dependent on the time of day.

Comment: @MatthewRead: oh, true, you're right. Well, nevermind, I was already convinced with your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5 questions isn't much to go by statistically, besides that 2 of the unanswered ones are from shortly before Christmas and the other from yesterday.  Two of them seem fairly obscure as well, so the whole I wouldn't be surprised.  Feel free to edit the older ones (ideally improving them) to bump them to the top of the Active list.

Our unanswered question rate is 15% with SO at 19%. I would have expected it to be higher than SO (we do get a lot of obscure questions), but I would agree it does seem a bit high regardless.  Our answer rate is not as high [as it was during Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts), either.

While I would say the site **is** "active", it's not perfect.  We discussed some of the site's issues before [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/578/1465).  If you have any ideas on how to address any of this, please share them.